# The/A or no article: Fishing line

Tags: articles, zero-article, uncountable-nouns

Does the word ***fishing line*** have a plural? Wikipedia says that there is a plural, and in the [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fishing-line) it is uncountable.

There are no articles in similar sentences:

> 1. Canada Goose Entangled in (***the***/***a***) fishing line
>      Humpback Whale Entangled in (***the***/***a***) Fishing Line

but there is an article when defining the word:

> 2. ***A*** fishing line is a cord used or made for angling.

Comment: `Humpback Whale Entangled in Fishing Line` looks more like a ***caption*** or a  ***title*** than a *sentence*. Don't try to learn grammar from titles and headlines.

Comment: Here, too, the article is used.:
"Where do you put the bobber on a fishing line?"

Comment: It would be better to include an example like that one in your question (not in a comment), while also telling us where it comes from (rather than depending on assumptions and guesswork).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of words that can be countable or uncountable depending on context. Fishing line is like "wire" and "thread" here. If you have a whole spool of it, it's uncountable: "We need to use fishing line (wire, thread) for this project."

If you cut a piece off, and start to use it (maybe for fishing), it can become countable: "A fishing line in the water is transparent, and the fish can't see it." "We solder a wire between that pin and ground." "There is a thread hanging from your coat."

In its countable sense "fishing line" has a plural form, "fishing lines."

Comment: Very clearly and concisely put.

Comment: Also, as to context, the lack of article referring to goose/whale establishes the use of countable/uncountable, since it clearly refers to geese or whales in general. The rather telegraphic style of the examples suggests use as captions for photographs.